# Multiple root node in asp.net SiteMapPath (Web.sitemap)

Tags: asp.net, sitemap, sitemappath, web.sitemap

I am implementing a Dashboard kind of web application, where users having different Roles.  I have to show Site Map Path at the top pf the page, as user browse the different pages inside the dashboard. I am using asp.net SiteMapPath, how can i use it for Multiple root node. i need to implement multiple root node as per users roles.

Ex:- 
Admin->Directory1->Directory2->Page1.aspx

Teacher->Directory1->Page2.aspx

Student->Directory2->Page1.aspx and so on.

Where Admin, Teacher, and Student are root node of the path.

It shouldn't be like Admin->Teacher->Directory1->Page2.aspx

Any solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the admin as your root node, and define everything in the `asp:Menu`,
in your case, use `<asp:Menu ID="mainMenu" DataSourceId="siteMapDataSource" runat="server" StaticDisplayLevels="2" StaticSubMenuIndent="0" />`
the `StaticDisplayLevels="2"` will make sure admin, teacher and student are always presented, and the indent will prevent it from appearing indented, as it is defined by default.

Comment: i am adding Admin as a root node, but its making Teacher and Student as a child of this, that i don't require.

Comment: Does it matter to you if "behind the scenes" admin is a parent to teacher and student? what Im suggesting is that it will be their parents, however, in the menu control, you set the StaticDisplayLevel to 2, thus defining that at all times, all 3 will be presented on the same level

Comment: @ShaharB What if i am not using asp.net menu controls and instead creating my own menu using ul and li.

Answer (score 0):

- three site Map file (For Admin, Teacher, Student) 
  We've placed these sitemap files into the App_Data folder, 
  In the user control, we create a public enum, to represent the different menus available.

  > ```
  > public enum SiteMapMenus
  > ```
  >
  > { Admin, Teacher, Student , NotSet }

  - Then created a public property to set the menu type at design time.

> ```
> SiteMapMenus eMenuToLoad = SiteMapMenus.NotSet;  
> public SiteMapMenus MenuToLoad  
> {  
>     get { return eMenuToLoad; }  
>     set { eMenuToLoad = value; }  
> }
> ```

- Now, The GetMenuDataSource method reads the required sitemap file as an XML file, then creates and returns a data source that can be bound to the control.

  > ```
  > XmlDataSource GetMenuDataSource(SiteMapMenus menu, string serverMapPath)  
  > {  
  >     XmlDataSource objData = new XmlDataSource();  
  >     objData.XPath = "siteMap/siteMapNode";  
  >    switch (menu)  
  >    {  
  > case SiteMapMenus.Admin:objData.DataFile=serverMapPath + @"\App_Data\Admin.sitemap";  
  >         break;  
  >     case SiteMapMenus.Teacher:
  > objData.DataFile=serverMapPath+@"\App_Data\Teacher.sitemap";  
  >                  break;  
  >             case SiteMapMenus.Student:
  > objData.DataFile=serverMapPath+@"\App_Data\Student.sitemap";  
  >                 break;  
  >     default:  
  >         break;  
  > }  
  > objData.DataBind();  
  > return objData;  
  > }
  > ```
- as the data source is now XML, and not in the format returned from the sitemap provider, we need to setup our databindings on the menu control itself.

> ```
>     <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server">     
>  <DataBindings>   
>          <asp:MenuItemBinding DataMember="siteMapNode" 
>          TextField="title" NavigateUrlField="url"  />   
>     </DataBindings>   
>  </asp:Menu>
> ```

- We can now finally bind the source to the control, and this is all fired off in the Page_Load event handler of the User Control.

  > ```
  > protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
  >   {  
  >      Menu1.DataSource = GetMenuDataSource(eMenuToLoad, 
  >                         Server.MapPath("~"));  
  >      Menu1.DataBind();  
  >   }
  > ```
- Using our new menu is now as easy as registering the user control on the page, and specifying which menu to display by setting the MenuToLoad property.

  > ```
  >    <DW:MyMenu ID="MyMenu1" runat="server" MenuToLoad="Secure" />
  > ```

Now, You can use different different site map for different different users.....